# How to find the date of the same day ( same week ) for the previous year ? ( SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table that contains dates , For each date I need to return a reference date: same day of the same number of the week but during the previous year.

For example let's suppose today is 03-03-2023 , the day is friday and the number of the week is 5 I  want as a resulat the date of friday in 2022 during the week number 5.

I have tried this formula but it didn't give me a good result

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, (DATEPART(week, @now) * 7 + DATEPART(weekday, @now)) - (DATEPART(week, DATEADD(year, -1, @now)) * 7 + DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(year, -1, @now))), DATEADD(year, -1, @now))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM6dt.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,

Comment: Calendar tables make this *much* easier. If you don't have one, invest the time to create one.

Comment: First and foremost, what is a "week number"? Some define them as starting from 1 jan, some use so called ISO-week, some use american week etc. ISO week number might be anything from 51 - 53, which makes comparing stuff to previous year tricky etc etc. You first need to figure out these rules, and then the easiest is to generate a table with all this information containing year, day number, week number, date. Then solving your problem would become a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -52, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this assume that all weeks of the year are equal to 52.
Maybe I will try applying this testing on the max number of weeks for every date I have.

Comment: Yes, Ideally `52` weeks is the standard in a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the ISO weeks definition, you can try the following.

```
CASE
WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(week, -52, @Date)) = YEAR(@Date)
THEN DATEADD(week, -52, @Date)
ELSE DATEADD(week, -53, @Date)
END
```

For about 80% of the cases, the -52 calculation will yield the correct result, otherwise (with one exception noted below) -53 gives the correct answer.

The only exceptional case is when the reference date is in ISO week 53 and the prior year only has 52 weeks. in that case, it will end up in week 52 of the prior year, which may be a reasonable accommodation.

If you wish to use a different week definition I believe the above can be adapted to `week` instead of `iso_week` and possibly use `SET DATEFIRST` to adjust the week boundaries.

If you don't care about ISO weeks or any other week-numbering scheme, and just want to get the closest date one year-ago on having the same day-of-week, then Nayanish's posted is the simple answer.  If you also want to always guarantee that year is offset by 1, then the following adjustment can be made:

```
CASE
WHEN DATEPART(year, DATEADD(week, -52, @Date)) < DATEPART(year, @Date)
THEN DATEADD(week, -52, @Date)
ELSE DATEADD(week, -53, @Date)
END
```